# Using TomEE and open JPA, i get the following error: SEVERE: JAVA AGENT NOT INSTALLED

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, openjpa, javaagents, apache-tomee

I'm getting the following error using TomEE and JPA:

```
SEVERE: JAVA AGENT NOT INSTALLED. 
The JPA Persistence Provider requested installation of a ClassFileTransformer which requires a JavaAgent.  
See http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/javaagent.html
```

Is having a java agent required for openJPA to function properly? (Specifically is it needed for "openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings")

If so, how do I install it properly in eclipse?

Answer (score 3):

```
-javaagent:openejb-javaagent-3.0-beta-2.jar
```

Add that to your VM arguments in the Eclipse run configuration.

Comment: I know this is an old post, but would you be able to solve this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65827818/error-when-adding-java-agent-in-vm-arguments-while-using-openjpa

Comment: You need to supply the full pathname of the agent JAR file. The file is located in TomEE's lib folder. Also the JAR file name is openejb-javaagent.jar in TomEE 8. Example: -javaagent:/tomee/lib/openejb-javaagent.jar.